# DFS Synchronization between truecrypt mounted volumes?

Tags: dfs, dfs-r, truecrypt

I setup DFS synchronization between two server in my network and it's working fine, But DFS is unable to sync my true-crypt container because of it's mounted every time and in mounted position the container having in locked mode.
So i thought to sync mounted volume of true-crypt via DFS, But DFS is again fails to sync and generating the following error in event log: -

The DFS Replication service failed to replicate the replicated folder at local path E:\DeploymentShare because the local path is not the fully qualified path name of an existing, accessible local folder.

I don't know that what's the real reason of this failure, but it seems like true-crypt do not allow to create system folder such as system volume information, recycle etc, in mounted volume.

Can anyone in this expert zone can help me about this issue?

Comment: Not sure exactly what your problem is, and you haven't provided enough details (though DFS troubleshooting is generally hellacious at the best of times), but DFS-R can work between true-crypt volumes.  Sounds like you have it configured wrong, though.  To sync a folder in DFS, the folder has to be shared, and my guess would be that your TrueCrypt volumes aren't shared out, which is what that error generally indicates.

Comment: I think he has the volume mounted in a share (as he says) and not exposed it - this is nice, but it is not, as I say in my answer, what dfs-r works with. the volume must be shared (it works on file shares) and acessible for the system (does not work in user session). The error is quite clear. THat said, dfs debugging is quite easy IF one knows the tools and is willing to work through a ton of long useless output ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use DFS and Truecrypt together.  I've done it.

Having said that, [the first hit on Google for your error message is a thread over at social.technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4a93d19a-00a9-44a9-8cea-a712a83a4de2/dfs-replication-failed?forum=windowsserver2008r2branchoffice), where the below advice can be found.

---

> After doing some research, it seems that third party disk encryption software will cause the issue, that it mounts volumes long after the OS has booted and DFSR has started running. So you may test if if the DFSR will work if you wait enough time.
>
> Also you can have a try to delete and recreate DFSR group if the issue did not occur directly after create the group.
>
> If issue still exists, you can test to stop DFSR service, renamed database GUID (x:\System Volume information\dfsr) from elevated command prompt,

---

> got it. it seems working now. will confirm tomorrow morning with the solution. thanks
>
> the answer is, deleted the replication group, deleted the DFSprivate folder from the folders setup for replication, recreated the replication groups. working like a charm. cheers for the help Shaon.

---

Delaying the start of the DFS replication and namespace services until after the volume is mounted also works, and is basically necessary, unless you want a headache to deal with every time the server reboots.  (Having said that, I never deployed this into production because there's just too much that can go wrong.  [Using Bitlocker in place of TrueCrypt, per TomTom's answer, is probably the better way to go](https://serverfault.com/a/574982/118258).)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Do not use truecrypt or do not use DFS - and ask an admin that you pay (this here is a place for admins, not for users needing help).

Basically DFS has a lot of requirements and it seems that the truecrypt mounted folder is not compatible with them - so it is not syncable. Simple like that. DFS is enterprise technology and makes a hell of a lot of assumptions.

You could try using bitlocker instead of truecrypt. Or mounting it as disc - not sure it can do that, never using it.

Comment: Grats to the coward. Hint: downvoting wont help that it is the right answer.

Comment: Actually, it's not the right answer, though... Truecrypt and DFS can work together (and I've gotten tho TrueCrypt volumes syncing with DFS), but it looks like the OP simply doesn't know how to set up DFS in general, or use Google, for that matter.

Comment: As i said - tons of requirement and the mounted folder like that is not compatible. Never used it though - I fall back to bitlocker in case i need it.